# Export Pipe Delimited Text File From R

Tags: r, file, text, export

I need to export a pipe delimited "|" txt file from [R] script.

Thanks!

Scottieie

Comment: Thanks Richard. That was super helpful and clever of you to help me out like that. Go team!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `write.table` provides the argument `sep` to define a separator.

Use `sep = "|"` to separate cells by a `|` character, e.g.:

```
write.table(data.frame(a=1:3,b=3:1), file = "output.txt", sep = "|")
```

Comment: That was exactly the answer. Thanks. I was so ingrained in write.csv that I didn't even consider write.table to a txt file and specifying the separator. 


write.table(source, file = "file.txt", sep = "|")


Many thanks.

Comment: Not sure if it adds a grace period to ensure you actually test the answer out?

Comment: So new I can't upvote you, not enough manna points or something.

Comment: Thanks. I guess you should try before verify (:

Answer (score 1):

A Tidyverse solution would be to use `write_delim()`:

```
write_delim(my_table, data/my_table.txt, delim = "|")
```

Check out the documentation [here](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/write_delim.html).